# Google Map API 10.2.6 - java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: 12291

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created a simple Google Map Application from the "New Project" dialog, and I have proeperly setup up and receive my key from Google API Console. For test purposes, I also downloaded a fresh Android N system image with Google Play Services support, as seen below:

[image]

Whatever I tried to do this exception will always occur:

[image]

Activity sample code:

`public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

`}`

I've done my research and as it seems this exception is thrown when Google Services is not installed. But I guaruntee they are. If I try to install it in a pure Android device, the app runs perfectly fine.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Ever figure this out? I only get this on an emulator, works fine on a physical device.

Comment: i have same issue. have you any solution?